# how to create single php class for MySQL data operations like update,insert that can be used for any tables

Tags: php

**how to create single php class for MySQL data operations like update,insert that can be used for any tables.

i want this class that can be used for any databases and tables

Comment: Hi, you cannot use only one class usually its min 4 classes. Use PDO

Comment: it's called "PDO"...

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, the best way to access data in databese it's PDO, but you also should use patterns in your code, to get well done code you should use ActiveRecord or DataMapper pattern. Google to understand it.

I prefer DataMapper because it has only dataccesss logic, instead of ActiveRecord use business logic in